# Using Dates in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file with columns that are dates. I have imported the file using the code: 
rx <-read.csv ("test.csv", sep = "," , header = TRUE) 
and now want to convert the field start_date into a date format so I can use date ranges to split my data set. In my csv file the field is in the format '01/01/2015'

Any help in doing that will be great.

thanks

Comment: Always use `read.csv ("test.csv", sep = "," , header = TRUE, as.is=TRUE)`. This will read in dates as character vectors, which is preferable to factors. To convert: as.Date(df$dateVar, format="%d/%m/%Y) if this is day/month/year. see `?as.Date`. and the many posts on SO. like this one [dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398131/date-conversion-from-dd-mm-yyyy).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Imo. You can convert using:

```
rx$start_date = as.Date(rx$start_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks for that guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use package ''lubridate'', which works on many date formats. Try the following codes

```
lubridate::dmy('01/01/2015')
lubridate::dmy('01/01/15')
lubridate::dmy('01/jan/15')
```

They all produce the same result

```
[1] "2015-01-01 UTC"
```