# How to modify date values?

Tags: r, date

How could I modify raw date values. For example.

```
> DF2
  Date     
1 11012018  
2 7312014  
3 6102015
4 10202017
```

Into modified date values the one with "/"

```
> DF2
  Date     
1 11/01/2018  
2 7/31/2014  
3 6/10/2015
4 10/20/2017
```

Comment: Do you want the column to be class of `character` or `date`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398131/convert-string-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Use `lubridate` for all date and time related tasks

```
> lubridate::mdy(c("11012018", "7/31/2014"))
[1] "2018-11-01" "2014-07-31"
```

You can also `format` it if needed:

```
format(lubridate::mdy(c("11012018", "7/31/2014")), "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "11/01/2018" "07/31/2014"
```

Assuming: your date is in month-date-year format. Else you can use other `lubridate` functions

Comment: Try the next entry `dmy("7312014")`

Comment: @RonakShah Corrected it

Comment: OP has input as `7312014` and want output as `7/31/2014`. You have taken input as `7/31/2014`.

Comment: Check their expected output, `7/31/2014`, they just want to put forward slashes as separator, it is not clear if they want it in date class.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use(It is assumed that you just need to add a new separator. In any case, you could convert back to date-time type):

```
new<-gsub("([0-9]{,2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})","\\1 \\2 \\3",df$Date)
gsub(" ","/",new)
#[1] "11/01/2018" "7/31/2014"  "6/10/2015"  "10/20/2017"
```

**Edit:**
More generally as suggested by @jay.sf ,

```
test4<-gsub("(^[0-1]?\\d)([0-3]?\\d)(\\d{4}$)","\\1 \\2 \\3",df$Date)
gsub(" ","/",test4)
#[1] "11/01/2018" "7/31/2014"  "6/10/2015"  "10/20/2017"
```

This is to account for such date formats as:

```
test3<-c("11012018", "1112015", "7312014", "7312014", "10202017", "772007", "772007", 
         "7072007")
```

Comment: nice, how would you generalize that to e.g. `772017`?

Comment: @jay.sf Interesting! Perhaps we could do it separately like so: `test<-"772017";
test1<-gsub("([0-9]{,2})([0-9]{,1})([0-9]{4})","\\1 \\2 \\3",test)` I'll see if I can write a more general solution.

Comment: I support that. Try this regex `"(^[0-1]?\\d)([0-3]?\\d)(\\d{4}$)"` and test it on `c(11012018, 1112015, 7312014, 7312014, 10202017, 772007, 772007, 7072007)`.

Comment: @jay.sf Added to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: also for `"0772007"`, my numeric code slightly failed

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:

```
df <- transform(df, V1 = as.Date(as.character(V1), "%d%m%Y"))
```

And another which may convert in the required mm/dd/yyyy format is as below:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), "%m%d%Y")))
```

Both the solutions are through the base R package.

Comment: It is month-day-year format, see 2nd row as example: "7/31/2014"

Comment: If that is the answer they want, all great, but then it is a duplicate post. Check their expected output, `7/31/2014`, they just want to put forward slashes as separator, it is not clear if they want it in date class.

Comment: Maybe I got confused, the data apparently looked numeric or integer.
Happy to delete my answer, if that's not the case!